# JIRA - Unable to add transitions to a status

Tags: jira

I created a workflow successfully, suddenly I came to know that I missed a status in it. I added the status "Patch Sent" but there's no option with it to Add Transitions. Whereas I added another status after is "Development Completed" and it has the option to add transitions. It is so confusing, and I have tried by every mean.

I edited using the edit button but it just gave the option to rename the status. Same is the case with View Property button, it does not do anything for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow and "Active versus inactive workflows". You'll need to deactivate or copy that workflow to make that change